# Удаление элементов списка в Прологе

Tags: prolog

Немного непонятна логика удаления.

```
remove_positive([],[]). % База рекурсии 
remove_positive([H|T],X):-H>0,remove_positive(T,X). % Исключаем положительный   элемент     из списка 
remove_positive([H|X],[H|Y]):-remove_positive(X,Y). % Остальные элементы оставляем как есть
```

вот эта строчка непонятна немного

```
remove_positive([H|X],[H|Y]):-remove_positive(X,Y). % Остальные элементы оставляем как есть
```

например исходный список `[-1,-5,3]` срабатывает последнее правило, только как?

```
remove_positive( [-1|-5,3],???) :- remove_positive([-5,3],?)
```

Comment: При подстановке получается

    remove_positive([-1|-5,3],[-1|Y]:-remove_positive([-5,3],Y).

То есть мы вынимаем из списка элемент и добавляем его в результат ([-1|Y]), а оставшуюся часть строки ("хвост") рекурсивно передаем в remove_positive().

Comment: а что тогда на следующей итерации будет?
    remove_positive(-5|3],??):-remove_positive([3],?)
Y  что пустой остается? или что в нем?

Comment: все, дошло наконец-то..рекурсия..брр.
спасибо Вам, insolor)

Comment: У самого в свое время от рекурсии мозги кипели, а сейчас ничего, нормально)

Comment: @insolor, стоит добавить ответ

Answer (score 1):

При подстановке `[-1,-5,3]` получается:

```
remove_positive([-1|[-5,3]],[-1|Y]:-remove_positive([-5,3],Y).
```

То есть мы вынимаем из списка элемент и добавляем его в результат `([-1|Y])`, а оставшуюся часть строки ("хвост") рекурсивно передаем в `remove_positive()`.

На следующей итерации будет вот что:

```
remove_positive([-5|[3]]],[-5|Y]):-remove_positive([3],Y).
```

Y в обоих случаях - "локальные" переменные, значение у них будет различное для разных вызовов. Когда будет достигнута база рекурсии, произойдет возврат по цепочке вызовов, и возвращаемое значение соберется из неположительных (`<=0`) элементов списка.